# Plot with action button depending on 2 inputs

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I'm trying to make something which has the following characteristics:

- It does not show anything at the start (no plot output), and
- It only updates after clicking the button (not when changing the first or second var)

So far I've used observeEvent and eventReactive but both have not yet worked. For this question I'm using iris as an example. I've been wracking my brain over this the past few hours and I've used many different techniques of observeEvent, eventReactive, isolate(), etc.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("plot example"),
        
        sidebarPanel(

                selectInput("var1", "First var",
                            list("Sepal length" = "Sepal.Length",
                                 "Sepal width"  = "Sepal.Width",
                                 "Petal length" = "Petal.Length",
                                 "Petal width"  = "Petal.Width")),
                
                selectInput("var2", "Second var",
                            list("Petal length" = "Petal.Length",
                                 "Petal width"  = "Petal.Width",
                                 "Sepal length" = "Sepal.Length",
                                 "Sepal width"  = "Sepal.Width")),
                actionButton("gobutton", "Go")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
                                 plotlyOutput("plot"))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
        
        # I want the plot only to update if I press "Go"
        # observe event only does this the first time
        #  observeEvent(eventExpr = {
        #          input$gobutton
        #  },
        #          handlerExpr = {
        # output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        #         iris_plot <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x=input$var1, 
        #                                      y=input$var2, 
        #                                      colour="Species")) + geom_point()
        #         ggplotly(iris_plot)
        # })
        #          })
        
        # this gives the error: Unknown input: reactive.event
        inputVar <- eventReactive(input$gobutton, {
                runif(input$var1, input$var2)
        })
        
        output$plot <- renderPlotly({
                iris_plot <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x=inputVar, 
                                                     y=inputVar,
                                                     colour="Species")) + geom_point()
                ggplotly(iris_plot)
        })
        
        # this below is the regular code
        # output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        #                  iris_plot <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x=input$var1,
        #                                               y=input$var2,
        #                                               colour="Species")) + geom_point()
        #                  ggplotly(iris_plot)
        # })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
rv <- reactiveValues(var1=NULL,var2=NULL)
observeEvent(input$gobutton,{
   rv$var1 <- input$var1
   rv$var2 <- input$var2
})
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(rv$var1) & !is.null(rv$var2)){
                iris_plot <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x=rv$var1, 
                                                     y=rv$var2,
                                                     colour="Species")) + geom_point()
                ggplotly(iris_plot)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

req(input$gobutton) should do the trick

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$gobutton)

    iris_plot <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x=input$var1,
                                         y=input$var2,
                                         colour="Species")) + geom_point()

    ggplotly(iris_plot)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But after pressing the button for the first time (works), it updates immediately without pressing the button again?